# How to find the last element in python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a web scraper for discord after logging in the bot should extract the last sent message in a discord channel and print it out. The last sent message however is dynamic. It always has a different path. It doesn't have an ID either. It only has a class name of `embedFooterText-28V_Wb`. As you know selenium returns the first element that has that class. In this case, it's the first message ever sent. How can I reverse it so it gets the last message sent? This is what I have written so far:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name('embedFooterText-28V_Wb').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(text)
```

This code returns the first message sent and I'd like to get the last message sent

Comment: share parth of the html please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find all of the elements the get last one with:

```
el1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'embedFooterText-28V_Wb')]")[-1]
```

but better to get last one already with xpath functionality

Comment: But this is the same what I answered previously.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(//*[contains(@class,'embedFooterText-28V_Wb')])[last()]`
I used `Java` syntax however in `Python` it will be quite similar

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: I made a small mistake with the syntax this works. Thanks!

Comment: @jamey67 why did you change the accepted answer from mine to Vova's?

Comment: What are you talking about?
I just asked you why did you removed the upvote you gave initially to my answer here?

Comment: @Eliyahu just found unnecessary